# SendGrid API send multiple emails using php ext-curl

Tags: php, curl, sendgrid, php-curl, sendgrid-api-v3

I am using SendGrid's API v3 to send emails. I am trying to schedule multiple emails to be sent in the future.

I have a form which triggers a POST request when submitted. The form contains two fields:

- The recipient's email address, and
- The hourly interval (the period of time to send each email)

From [their docs](https://sendgrid.api-docs.io/v3.0/mail-send/v3-mail-send), I note that scheduling more than 72 hours in advance is forbidden. Therefore, I am attempting to send X number of emails to the recipient until the 72 deadline is reached.

For instance, assuming that the hourly intervals defined above is 10, the recipient will receive an email every 10 days until the 7th email (because the 8th email would be forbidden under the 72-hour rule).

### Code

```
$email_to = $obj['q4_email'];
$hourlyInterval = $obj['q3_hoursTill'];

$now = time();
// convert hourlyInterval to seconds
$secondsInterval = $hourlyInterval * 60 * 60;

// SendGrid does not allow sending emails more than 72 hours in advance
// calculate 72 hours from now
$max_send_time = $now + (72 * 60 * 60);

// string to be included in CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS
$personalizations = "";

// until 72 hours has been passed
while ($next_send_time < $max_send_time) {
    // concat the strings together
    $personalizations .= "{\"to\":[{\"email\":\"" . $email_to . "\"}],\"subject\":\"Hello, World!\",\"send_at\":" . $next_send_time . "},";

    // increment to next schedule send time
    $next_send_time += $secondsInterval;
}

// remove trailing comma
$personalizations = substr($personalizations, 0, -1);
$personalizations = "[" . $personalizations . "]";

// send the email
curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
    CURLOPT_URL => $api_endpoint . "/mail/send",
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
    CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
    CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
    CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
    CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => "{\"personalizations\":" . $personalizations . ",\"from\":{\"email\":\"" . $email_from . "\"},\"reply_to\":{\"email\":\"" . $email_from . "\"},\"content\":[{\"type\":\"text/plain\",\"value\":\"Hello world newwest test: " . $next_send_time . "\"}]}",
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
        "authorization: Bearer " . $api_key,
        "content-type: application/json"
    ),
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);
$err = curl_error($curl);

if ($err) {
    echo "cURL Error #:" . $err;
} else {
    echo $response;
}

curl_close($curl);
```

### Error message

The emails are not being sent/received.

I am assuming that there is something wrong with my syntax in the $personalizations string!? But can't figure out what..

Comment: What’s very _wrong_ here to begin with, is that you are assembling JSON manually. Don’t do that. Populate the according PHP data structures, and then use `json_encode`.

Comment: _“Error message - The emails are not being sent/received.”_ - that’s not really an error message though is it, that is your (very rudimentary) problem description. What actual response did you get from the API?

Comment: Thank you @CBroe for the feedback. I have assembled it manually as that it from the docs linked above. 

There is no response returned from the API as far as I can tell..

Comment: 1) That is not a good reason. The probability that you are introducing errors when creating this manually, is just higher, than when you just let json_encode take care of it. 2) Sounds unlikely, that an API would give no response whatsoever.

Answer (score 0):

You can make the the string of emails which is required in send grid personalisation parameter like this:

```
$email = "";
    foreach ($emails as $email){
        $email .= '{"email":"'.$email.'"},';
    }

$personalize_data='{"personalizations":[{"to":['.$email.'],"dynamic_template_data":{
```